# Displaying HTML fields in django admin change list

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to use HTML in fields in a model's admin's change_list template?

For example: I would like to make the *Site domain* column clickable, and to be able to navigate to that site:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a function `clickable_site_domain()` which returns a HTML link as per the value of `site_domain`. Then you need to add this method name to the `ModelAdmin.list_display` attribute. Finally, you need to mark the string safe to avoid HTML escaping with `mark_safe`.

Prior to Django 1.9, you would need to set `allow_tags=True` for this function to avoid HTML escaping. [(Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
from django.utils.text import mark_safe # Older versions
from django.utils.html import mark_safe # Newer versions


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (..,'clickable_site_domain', ..) # add the custom method to the list of fields to be displayed.

    def clickable_site_domain(self, obj):
        # return HTML link that will not be escaped
        return mark_safe(
            '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (obj.site_domain, obj.site_domain)
        )
```

Comment: ahhh so the key is allow_tags

Comment: `allow_tags` does not HTML-escape the output.

Comment: `allow_tags` has been deprecated. The correct way to do this now is to mark the string as safe via `mark_safe`.

Comment: Not sure if/when this changed but in Django 2.2 you must import `mark_safe` from `django.utils.html`, so the first line should read: `from django.utils.html import mark_safe`

Answer (score 11):

A more recent answer as of 2019 in `django 2.2`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'custom_field', ...]

    def custom_field(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a href={}>URL</a>', obj.url)
```

Answer (score -4):

Should be doable [in ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template).

Edit: See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) for how options are defined in the ModelAdmin, and then just do that appropriately when you register in admin.py, making sure your template exists, so for example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'myapp/mymodel_change_list.html'
```

Comment: How, can you explain?

Comment: Added, but @Rahul Gupta's answer is obviously better, I missed that option.

Comment: irrelevant to what op wants

Comment: @rowman Incorrect, though it is definitely **NOT** a good way to do this and it is now referring to Django docs for a version that is EOL. You can override this template or specific blocks if you want or need to customize content in the change list view. To reiterate, it is **NOT** a good way to achieve what op wants, but to state that the template is "irrelevant" to what is rendered on the change list view misses a key part of how the admin classes and templates fit together, even if I agree this is the wrong way to do it and this answer lacks sufficient detail to get all the way there.

Comment: @Jmills, yes I admit that the response is not irrelevant given your explanation.