# Django: where is mark_safe located

Tags: django

The `mark_safe` function is located in `django.utils.safestring` and as far I could check always has been. Why are the different import locations examples on internet ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976000/displaying-html-fields-in-django-admin-change-list/32976341) and [here](https://books.google.sk/books?id=cuh1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=%22from+django.utils.text+import+mark_safe%22&source=bl&ots=uf4DbswGc_&sig=ACfU3U05BQVbH83g9GrvVmOWbMJqDivrkQ&hl=sk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiovu67qpHlAhVHQMAKHRnnCZ4Q6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22from%20django.utils.text%20import%20mark_safe%22&f=false))?

More importantly why are these other imports (`django.utils.html` and `django.utils.text`) working? I have some in my project and until Django version bumped to 2.2 my project was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imports are working because the function is imported in those files.

so for example if you import mark_safe in your a.py you can write in b.py:

```
from .a import mark_safe
```

but the better (and correct) way is to import the function from
`django.utils.safestring` because it is defined there.

The problem is it will not longer work if the function is not longer imported in those files.

Answer (score 1):

The [documented location](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.safestring) for `mark_safe` has always been `django.utils.safestring` so you should import it from there.

Until [this change](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b004bd62e83588fdb0e533fdeec993aec358281d#diff-f614fc7a7dbb2882be1692a448abd21f) in Django 2.2, `mark_safe` was imported into `django.utils.text`. So it was possible (but not a good idea) to import from there.

In the current [master branch](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ee6b17187fbf19d498c16bd46ec6dd6aaf86f453/django/utils/html.py#L14), `mark_safe` is imported in `django.utils.html`, so it is possible but not advised to import it from there.